# Running two processes in Unix/Linux

Tags: linux, unix

When the kernel creates two processes whose code section is same, does the kernel actually copy the code to the virtual address space of both processes? In other words, if I create two processes of the same program, in memory, do we have two copies of the program or just one copy?

Obviously, it may depend on implementation but I'm asking in traditional Unix OS.

Answer (score 3):

> Does the kernel actually copy the code to the virtual address space of both processes?

The text segment will be mapped (rather than copied) into the virtual address space of each process, but will be referring to the same physical space (so the kernel will only have one copy of the text in memory).

The data and bss segments will also be mapped into the virtual address space of each process, but these will be created per process.  At process initiation, the data from the data and bss segments from the executable will be mapped/copied into the process's virtual memory; if it was not copied ab initio then as soon as the processes start writing to the data the process will be given its own private copy.

Clearly, shared memory and mmap'd memory are handled after the process starts.  Shared memory is always shared between processes; that's its raison d'être.  What happens with mmap depends on the flags used, but it is often shared too.

Comment: But then how does kernel know that text section is already present in memory? I mean which kernel data structure is used?

Comment: That depends on which kernel...it probably uses the inode number for the executable in the per process table, plus something in the memory mapping tables, but I've not looked in detail.  It's the kernel's job to worry about that — not mine.

Answer (score 2):

Modern operating systems will use [Copy-on-Write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) to avoid duplicating pages until they are actually updated.  Note that on many systems (including Linux) this can lead to overcommit, where the OS doesn't actually have enough RAM to cope with all the copying required should every process decide to modify un-duplicated pages.

Comment: I think you meant to say COW.